# Ubuntu partitioning and dual boot install on Lenovo IdeaCentre Q190

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, uefi

I just purchased a Lenovo IdeaCentre Q190, which has secure boot and uefi. I have minimized the Windows 8 partition to 100 GB. What I need to know is:
1) Should I move the free space to the end of the disk?
2) I need some help partitioning the free space to a /root, a swap and a /home partition.

Answer (score 0):

**@1)** You don't really need to move that free space, although some people recommend to do so.

**@2)** While installing you could either choose "guided install on the largest free space".

**--** If you want to select partition options by hand, then choose "custom install". Continue by creating a new primary partition with swap-filesystem. The size should be something between 2 and 8 GB. Tell the computer to use the partition as swap.

**--** At next create a new primary partition with ext4 filesystem, size something between 15 und 20 GB, or maybe 30. Tell ubuntu to use that as / .

**--** Then create a new primary partition with ext4 filesystem. The size could be all the rest of the space. You don't really need a seperate home partition, so you could skip that step and use the homefolder that comes in the root-partition created in the previous step. In this case increase the size of the root-partition.

**--** Last but not least tell ubuntu where to install the boot loader. I assume you want to keep secure boot active, so proceed to install it on the first partion, the efi partition.